# dragged JDialog gets behind Window

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a JDialog created with owner null (I can see from the source code that if the supplied owner is null, Java will get me SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame() which is going to be used as the owner).

The problem is that now an then, when I drag that JDialog it gets behind the main Window. Which is quite maddening because it happens sporadically.

Can someone please explain why would this happen and under which conditions? (I'm using Java 7.17 x64 and Windows 7).

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe. As the problem is intermittent, see also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: You don't have any mouse actions that might cause the main window from been brought "toFront" or timers or other action that might cause this?

Comment: after more struggling I can see this: if I click on the Window bar, it gets the focus which is correct. if I click on the JDialog bar I can see that it's not getting the focus which remains to the Window.

Comment: Again, with an SSCCE we can't help, so I guess your struggles will continue...

Comment: Why not just make the JDialog's owner the main Window?